# Rotate a player on sphere using joystick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate my player on a sphere in unity and using this code to rotate it but it works on some positions on the sphere, can anyone help to solve this issue? or [click](https://youtu.be/mVjTG7HkUE4) the link to watch problem video.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;


public class Follow_guide_pos : MonoBehaviour {

     private Vector3 input;

     void Update () {
    //rotation of player input
    input = new Vector3(CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal_rot"),CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Vertical_rot"),0);
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
    //rotation of player output
    transform.LookAt(transform.position+input,transform.up);


   }
}
```

[Link to the video](https://youtu.be/mVjTG7HkUE4) is the video of the problem. 0:03-0:07 the plane is rotating correctly
but after moving it in other direction it is rotating on a different axis or not rotating as it was doing before.

Answer (score 1):

The LookAt function takes an "up" direction to help it align the object in the desired orientation.  As you move around the sphere, the true "up" of your vehicle is changing.  So you need to change the the "up" vector in LookAt to match the desired "up" of your vehicle.